# How can I use the result of a Split function (a Variant) in a Application.Left function (which needs a Range or String)?

Tags: excel, vba, split, user-defined-functions

I want to use this UDF on cells which contain multiple hexcodes separated by a comma. The main issue I'm currently facing is that String array created by the Split function cannot be used in the Application.Left function in the second UDF. Type conversion functions like Cstr seem to only work for numerical or string values. How can I solve this?

```
Function Gen_Col(Full_Hex As Range) As String

Dim Seperate1() As Variant
Dim code As Variant
Dim Dcode As Range
Dim Dec_Range As Range
Dim Color As Range

Set Dec_Range = Range("Table3[DEC]")
Seperate1 = Split(Full_Hex, ",")

Gen_Col = ""
For Each code In Seperate1
    If Gen_Col <> "" Then
        Set Dcode = Dec_Range.Find(DecCode(code), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not Dcode Is Nothing Then
                Color = Dcode.Offset(0, 3)
                Gen_Col = Gen_Col & ", " & Color.Value
            End If
    Else
        If Not Dcode Is Nothing Then
            Color = Dcode.Offset(0, 3)
            Gen_Col = Color.Value
        End If
    End If
Next code

End Sub
```

```
Function DecCode(code As Variant) As String
Dim L1
Dim H1
Dim MR1
Dim L2
Dim H2
Dim MR2
Dim L3
Dim H3
Dim MR13
Dim M
Dim I

'I'm translating the hexcode to the nearest decimal code from a list (hence the MRound with 51), and then using the color name of the respective decimal code selected from a pre-made list of names.

L1 = Application.Left(code, 2)
H1 = Application.Hex2Dec(L1)
MR1 = Application.MRound(H1, 51)
L2 = Application.Mid(code, 3, 2)
H2 = Application.Hex2Dec(L2)
MR2 = Application.MRound(H2, 51)
L3 = Application.Right(code, 2)
H3 = Application.Hex2Dec(L3)
MR3 = Application.MRound(H3, 51)

M = Application.Match(MR1 & MR2 & MR3, Range("Table3[DEC]"), 0) 
'"Table3[DEC]" contains a list of decimal codes.

I = Application.Index(Range("Table3[Name]"), M, 1) 
'"Table3[Name]" is a list of names for each color based on the decimal code from [DEC].

DecCode = I

End Sub
```

Comment: `Split` returns an array of string. Change definitions `Seperate1() As String`  and `code As String` (in both places). Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Also note that one should loop the array using `LBound` to `Ubound`, not a `For Each` loop: `Dim i As Long`, `For i = LBound(Seperate1) to UBound(Seperate1)`, `code = Seperate1(i)`.

Comment: With those suggestions + some extra fixes it now works!

Answer (score 1):

Made it work thanks to @FunThomas, @BigBen, and some extra fixes.
Needed to change `Separate1` and `code` to String, stop using `Application.` for the Left, Mid, and Right functions, and change most of the `For Each` section.

```
Function Gen_Col(Full_Hex As Range) As String

Dim Seperate1() As String
Dim code As String
Dim Dcode As String
Dim Dec_Range As Range
Dim Color As Range
Dim i As Long

Seperate1 = Split(Full_Hex, ",")

Gen_Col = ""
For i = LBound(Seperate1) To UBound(Seperate1)
    code = Seperate1(i)
    If Gen_Col <> "" Then
        Dcode = DecCode(code)
        Gen_Col = Gen_Col & ", " & Dcode
    Else
        Dcode = DecCode(code)
        Gen_Col = Dcode
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

```
Function DecCode(code As String) As String
Dim L1
Dim H1
Dim MR1
Dim L2
Dim H2
Dim MR2
Dim L3
Dim H3
Dim MR13
Dim M
Dim i

L1 = Left(code, 2)
H1 = Application.Hex2Dec(L1)
MR1 = Application.MRound(H1, 51)
L2 = Mid(code, 3, 2)
H2 = Application.Hex2Dec(L2)
MR2 = Application.MRound(H2, 51)
L3 = Right(code, 2)
H3 = Application.Hex2Dec(L3)
MR3 = Application.MRound(H3, 51)

M = Application.Match(MR1 & MR2 & MR3, Range("Table3[DEC]"), 0)

i = Application.Index(Range("Table3[Name]"), M, 1)

DecCode = i

End Function
```